# Error at admin customer Form

Tags: magento2, customer

I was trying to create a customer attribute.I made some mistakes in the code so I got error while editing existing customer and adding new customer.Now I remove the whole module,cleaned cache,run setup upgrade but still getting the same error.
I attach it below.Please help me to resolve the error.[image]

Comment: Find attribute nagento_username in eav_attribute table

Comment: I find it,What should I do next ?

Comment: first take backup of eav_attribute table then delete that magento_username attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your customer attribute from eav_attribute table **magento_username**.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your customer attribute from `eav_attribute` table.

Comment: I cannot find that one at eav_attribute table